# NodeJS + Template engine render slower comparing PHP

Tags: php, performance, node.js, pug, template-engine

Hi i use NodeJS with Template engine [ECT](https://github.com/baryshev/ect) and MongoDB for data.

Now i have simple code that i will render:
150 x FOO.

When i render it with Node.js template engine (ECT) the response time is: **1855ms**

With PHP response time is: **24ms**

Node.js ECT code:

```
<?- "FOO"; ?>
<?- "FOO"; ?>
<?- "FOO"; ?>
<?- "FOO"; ?>
<?- "FOO"; ?>
...
```

PHP code:

```
<?php echo 'FOO'; ?>
<?php echo 'FOO'; ?>
<?php echo 'FOO'; ?>
<?php echo 'FOO'; ?>
<?php echo 'FOO'; ?>
...
```

Cache is off.

And how bigger the count the slower becomes NodeJS app (ECT)

Is there something that i miss?

PS: I used also NodeJS + [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/). It seems even slower.

**Update:**

Tutorial to reproduce the issue (NodeJS app with Jade):

- Try to checkout this app:
  [NodeJS-app](https://github.com/ijason/NodeJS-Mongoose/tree/master/MongooseExample)
- Change "views/index.jade" file to:

  ```
  extends layout

  block content
      input(type="text" value="#{'FOO'}")
      input(type="text" value="#{'FOO'}")
      input(type="text" value="#{'FOO'}")...//150x FOO (not "for" loop)
  ```

NodeJS: v0.10.22

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8

Linux: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Comment: check this http://ectjs.com/#benchmark there's also a git repo on the tests they've made

Comment: You must be doing something very wrong.. My nodejs pages always return in less than 10ms, and that is with way more logic involved :)

Comment: @ExxKA, i have a form page that uses a lot of inline data.
like <input name="fname" value="#{user.name}"> (Jade). And if i visit it for a first time it loads for about 10sec. After debugging i found that if i place a lot of inline code then the ECT/Jade template engine render it very slow.

Comment: Right, but isn't that because Jade is caching it the first time around? One solution could be to compute all the templates when you initiate the server, so that they are cached and ready to go..

I have never used Jade myself, so I am not sure if you would get better performance using something else. Mustache has always served me well.

Comment: @BogdanLewis, can you share a bit more information regarding your Node.js setup (system, version etc.)? 1855ms seems to be a lot. I would also consider checking your network settings - maybe the delay comes form there. When Jade template is compiled, the engine creates JavaScript function and it should not take more than 50 - 100 ms (even on a slow machine). I usually get 12 - 15 ms with no Jade cache enabled.

Comment: Unless you need to support clients with disabled JavaScript, don't use templates. They're unmaintainable nightmares and it's not 2005. Write a client side app and communicate JSON data to populate pages via REST calls! Delegate the rendering to the client. ;)

Comment: Ok, i've updated the question. Added the tutorial.

Comment: Following your instructions, runing node 0.10.20 on OSX Mavericks, I get

    GET / 200 65ms - 4.7kb

Having said that, and following others' comments, there's evidently something to doublecheck on your own your setup. 

Above that, it could be easier to troubleshoot looking at your actual .js code, and the way you are implementing ECT. The linked example is using a different template engine as you noted, and it runs fine elsewhere.

Comment: @SergioMajluf, i've checked all. Everything is correct. The strange is if i add "for loop" with 1000 iterations it works fast (34ms), but if i place them all under each other then it renders (>500ms).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Jade is really slow, and may be slowest template engine (and that is not a secret).
And the second problem - **you're comparing template engine with PHP printing function**, this is wrong. Try compare with Node's util.log or console.log for convenience OR try echo in some template engine for php (like smarty or something else) :)

Also, if you wan speed - try doT (https://github.com/olado/doT)
BTW, express default mode is development, try this with jade

> NODE_ENV=production node app.js